# Why isn't this instance variable being recognized?

Tags: objective-c

In my .h:

```
@class PanelController;

@interface PanelController : NSWindowController <NSWindowDelegate>
{
    NSURL *zURL;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSURL *zURL;

@end
```

In my .m:

```
@synthesize zURL;

...

- (IBAction)openBrowser:(id)sender {
    self.zUrl = [zOpenPanel URL];
}
```

Error:

```
zURL not found on object PanelController
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the code block? You wrote "self.zUrl" which is != "self.zURL" if that's what you meant. The error string has zURL which implies something's wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Because Objective-C is case sensitive.

You use `self.zUrl` but it should be `self.zURL`.

(Also, the instance variable declaration might be unnecessary if you declare a property.)

Comment: It's still necessary under 32-bit OS X, IIRC.

Comment: (Addendum: it's necessary under the old runtime (32-bit OS X) if you're not implementing the property method(s) yourself, as it doesn't support synthesized ivars.)